# How to iterate fields and remove Null values and spaces

Tags: arcpy, null

Is it possible to iterate fields in a table to remove Null values and spaces (where there is no value)?  In other words, I would like to replace Null and " " with "" (no space).

Cobbling arcpy scripts, I have this:

```
import arcpy

fc = "{path to geodatabase and feature class}"
fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
for field in fieldList:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, [fieldList]) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row[0] == None:
                row[0] = ''
            elif row[0] == ' ':
                row[0] = ''
                cursor.updateRow(row)

print "Processing complete"
```

I'm aware of using "remove" in the field calculator, but you have to go field by field.  I'd like to do this for the whole table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that it's possible to calculate for an entire table at once, you will still need to calculate field by field.

As far as actually performing the edit the best way to update the data would be with `arcpy.CalculateField_management` - which is effectively the field calculator in your Python script - rather than an Update Cursor (which has to operate row at a time). You can use a Python expression in `arcpy.CalculateField_management` (or the field calculator itself) to check a string and return the updated string, for example:

```
(!field_name! or "").strip() # will also strip the trailing spaces
```

Which you can throw at `arcpy.CalculateField_management` in a script;

```python
import arcpy

fc = "{path to geodatabase and feature class}"
fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(fc, field_type="String") # don't want to try this on an integer

for field in fieldList:
    expression = """(!{}! or "").strip()""".format(field.name)
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, field.name, expression, "PYTHON_9.3")
```

Comment: My table has 52 fields, including 1 Object ID, 1 Geometry, and 3 Double type fields.  That's 47 fields I'd rather not individually recalculate to remove null values and single spaces.  The 5 fields are fairly obvious that I wouldn't need to check for type before running the calculation.  I would just skip those.  It's just that running the calculation on 47 fields, one-by-one is super tedious.

Comment: @Lance Sorry, should have made that clearer - you can call the field calculator as part of a Python script with `arcpy.CalculateField_management` which processes an entire column at once, rather than having to worry about row by row. Answer updated to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!  I added a print statement at the end to know when the script completed.  Took a bit more than 5 min. to run, but a lot less tedious than me doing it!  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

I think you've got it the wrong way around. Not `for field in fieldList` then `for row in cursor`, rather `for row in cursor` and `for field in fieldList` except you will need to index properly... you're only trying to adjust the first field in the fieldList with row[0].

```
import arcpy

fc = "{path to geodatabase and feature class}"
fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
# remove some key fields from the list
desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)

fieldList.remove(desc.shapeFieldName)
fieldList.remove(desc.OIDFieldName)

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, [fieldList]) as cursor:
    fRange = range(len(fieldList)) # create an index 0 to the number of elements in fieldList - 1

    for row in cursor:
        SomethingUpdated = False # a flag for changes

        # step through each field in the row by its index
        for index in fRange:
            if row[index] == None:
                row[index] = ''         #set the field to empty string
                SomethingUpdated = True #flag to store row
            else:
                val = str(row[index]).replace(" ","") # remove spaces
                if len(val) == 0:
                    # value is nothing but spaces or empty
                    row[index] = ''         #set the field to empty string
                    SomethingUpdated = True #flag to store row

        if SomethingUpdated:
            cursor.updateRow(row)

print "Processing complete"
```

Be aware that no checking is being done for field types; trying to set '' into a numeric field will cause this script to crash hard!

Answer (score 3):

I shall offer my variation:

```
import arcpy

fc = "{path to geodatabase and feature class}"

fieldList = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc) if f.type == "String"]

if fieldList:

    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, [fieldList]) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            for i in range (len(fieldList)):
                if not row[i]:
                    row[i] == ""
                elif row[i] == " ":
                    row[i] == ""
            cursor.updateRow(row)

print "Processing complete"
```

Comment: I like how you put together your field list of only string fields! Users new to python can find the single line syntax a bit confusing, would you mind expanding the construction of the field list please.

Comment: I like this answer, though to be extra safe I would modify the elif slightly:  elif row[i].rstrip() == "":  ...   That way you'll also pick up any instances of 2 or more spaces.

Comment: @Michael That list formation syntax took me a while to get down in my head as well. the basic format is [{code}var{code} for var in [list] if var{logic test}]. The syntax is a method of working with lists to create other lists. So for my code, the new list is populated with each field object's name from the listfields code if that field's type is string. It probably makes even less sense now.

Comment: Conceptually, this is exactly what I'm looking for.  However, I ran the script as provided and got the error:  File "C:\Test\RemoveNullAndSpaces.py", line 7, in <module>
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, [fieldList]) as cursor:
TypeError: 'field_names' must be string or non empty sequence of strings

Comment: try modifying the list comprehension to: ... if t.type.lower() == "string".  The error is saying that the list of field names is empty.  Also, it's good to add print statements so you can keep track of what's going on.  print the fieldList after the line where you create it.

Comment: @Lance the error you describe will happen when there are no string fields in your feature class. I'll throw in an if/then statement to my code as a check against this.

Comment: Actually, both f.type == "String" and f.type.lower() == "string" return the list of string-only field names.  Not sure if it matters, but the list is looks like [u'ALPHA', u'OBRD', and so on.  It seems to be something in the second half of the code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that I understand what you are asking, because your question does not describe what is not working in your code, but I think:

```
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == None:
            row[0] = ''
        elif row[0] == ' ':
            row[0] = ''
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

needs to be:

```
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == None:
            row[0] = ''
        elif row[0] == ' ':
            row[0] = ''
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

You will also need to filter out text fields from your other fields because they are the only ones you can write strings to.

Answer (score 1):

```
fc = inFeature # feeature class containing the null values
Row = # field containing the null values
selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc, "New_Selection", "Row is NULL") # selects the rows with null values
arcpy.DeleteRows_management(fc) # deletes selected rows
```

Comment: Please add a little explanation to your code.